# Ngninx "cannot load certificate BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission", help fix this [emerg] error

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, ssl-certificate-errors

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP server on a Raspberry Pi 4. In my nginx errror logs I am getting the following error:

```
2023/05/29 11:51:40 [emerg] 3356#3356: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/postfixadmin.mysite.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/postfixadmin.mysite.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
```

I'm assuming that this means Nginx is somehow unable to access my certificates. However, my site `postfixadmin.mysite.com` is still working perfectly. What exactly does this error indicate, and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Off topic, but most probably permissions.